# react useEffect detect if record is found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am doing this

`const data = useQuery("query");`

It returns `{good:'nice'}`

I have

```
useEffect(() => {
   if(!data) { 
      // show not found  
   }

}, [data])
```

In the `useEffect`, `data` is null in the first rerender, and then becomes the actual value in 2nd render, because `useQuery` takes time.

I need to show `not found record` in the above, but I can't distinguish if record was not found or if it's the n-th render where data hasn't been returned yet.

How do you solve this as the best practice ? i don't want to bring another variable to be tracking this. It seems so bad.

Comment: Is `data` a `null` value when no record is found?

Comment: yeap............

Answer (score 0):

useQuery returns the property `isLoading`. You can use this.

[Reference](https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/useQuery)

Comment: I think the actual problem is that I am also using `onCompleted` hook and `loading` value changes from true to false, but `onCompleted` is not called at this point and my `useEffect` re-renders again with `loading= false, data = null` value first and then `loading=false, data = actual data`